# Django "reverse for ____ with arguments"... error

Tags: python, django

I'm receiving the following error

> Error: Reverse for `placeinterest` with arguments `('',)` and keyword arguments `{}` not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>
> `[u'polls/(?P<section_id>[0-9]+)/placeinterest/$']`

I worked through the Django example for a polling app, and now I'm trying to create a class registration app adapting what I already have. Error points to line 5 here:

```
<h1>{{ section.class_name }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:placeinterest' section.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="radio" name="incr" id="incr" value="incr" />
<label for="incr"></label><br />
<input type="submit" value="Placeinterest" />
</form>
```

But I think the problem is in my placeinterest function:

```
def placeinterest(request, section_id):
    section = get_object_or_404(Section, pk=section_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = section.num_interested
    except (KeyError, Section.num_interested.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'section': section,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        section.num_interested += 1
        section.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(section.id,)))
```

I'm not sure what my POST call should be if my Section class looks like this:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    num_interested = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)
    def some_interested(self):
        if self.num_interested > 0:
            return "There is currently interest in this class"
        else:
            return "There is currently no interest in this class"
```

The results part comes up fine in my browser, and here is urls.py for good measure:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<section_id>[0-9]+)/placeinterest/$', views.placeinterest, name='placeinterest'),
]
```

Edit: adding the original code from the example in hopes that might help someone see where I went wrong:

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

vote function in views.py:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

detail.html, where I'm having problems after making my changes:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with your view. It specifically says it's trying to match the URL named `placeinterest` in the error. It knows the URL exists, but the arguments are wrong.

It thinks you're trying to pass an empty string as a positional argument. This means that `section.id` is probably `None` when the template is rendered. It's converting the null value into an empty string and passing it as a positional argument, hence `('',)`. That's a tuple with one empty string value in it.

Comment: Any idea what I should change? I tried to just mirror the way I created Question in the tutorial when I created Section.

Comment: Make sure the `section` context variable being passed to the template isn't `None`. Most likely somewhere along the line it's either not being returned correctly from the database or its being altered/reset.

Comment: But I've just copied exactly what I did for the tutorial, and that worked. The only difference is between the vote/placeinterest functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:placeinterest' section.id %}" method="post">
```

Django can't figure out the url argument as it's misconfigured. Use this:

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:placeinterest' section_id=section.id %}" method="post">
```

You also need to ensure that section id is valid a number (be careful of what you supply as `"section"` as your context.

Comment: The url tag allows args like `section.id`, so changing to `section_id=section.id` will not help.

Comment: alasdair is correct. `section_id=section.id` did not fix the issue

Comment: Have you tried to output section.id to see if it's truly in the context?